# Convert colorful logo to white only logo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a logo that the user uploaded in PNG format.

[image]

My goal is to convert that logo that the user uploaded into white color.

Like this - so that it look nice on a darker background.

[image]

I can export it and use a Photoshop to get what I want, but I want to programmatically do it.

Is there any API/Packages that help me achieve this?

I'm open to any suggestions. Feel free.

---

## I've tried

## PHP

```
<?php

    $logoSrc = '/images/logo.png?q=<?php echo microtime();';
    $logo = imagecreatefromstring($logoSrc);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($logo, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($logo, $white);

  ?>
```

---

## IMG

```
<img class="logo-external" src="{{imagefilter($logo, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 255, 255)}}">
```

---

## Result

`imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could remove the whitespace with [`imagecolortransparent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php):

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $white);
```

And then try using [`imagefilter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) to make the remaining image white:

```
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 255, 255)
```